# Chris Bane's PullToRefresh Customization

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

I am using PullToRefresh Library from Chris Banes ans need a little help with it.

I want to change the default text shown while pulling, refreshing and loading my data. I did the below and I was able to change it.

```
mPullToRefreshGridView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setPullLabel(
            getString(R.string.product_pull_label));
mPullToRefreshGridView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setRefreshingLabel(
            getString(R.string.product_refresh_label));
mPullToRefreshGridView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setReleaseLabel(
            getString(R.string.product_release_label));
```

However, my refresh label is a bit wider and thus overlaps the loading image like this (I don't wish to reduce my text unless thats the last option).

[image]

I have read the [doc on customization](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/wiki/Customisation) but could not find any resource for this. Could some one please help me to get this right?

Comment: You need to modify `pull_to_refresh_header_vertical.xml` of this lib.

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj Kumar. I now know where to make the changes. :) I reduced the padding to the footer view and the over-lapping has gone. :) Is this the only way?

Comment: Yes. It seems this is the only way :)